# Linear model: include quadratic interactions if you add a quadratic term?

Tags: r, regression, quadratic

I am working on a GLMM and want to know: if you add a quadratic term to one variable (`x1^2`) do you also then need to include a quadratic term in any of its interactions (e.g. `x1:x2`)?

My formula:

```r
quadratic.model(glmm) <- y ~ x1 + + I(x1^2) + x2 + x1:x2 + I(x1^2):x2
```

OR how would I know if I should only apply it to the focal variable (`x1`)?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement, if any, goes the other way.  That is, it is generally true that if you have an interaction in your model, you should include all the components of that interaction (there are some exceptions to this).  Also, it is generally true that, if you have a quadratic, you should have the linear of that variable (again, there are exceptions).

But no, just because you have e.g. $x_1$ and $x_1^2$ and $x_2$ and $x_1x_2$, there is no requirement to have $x_1^2x_2$. You can choose to include such a term based on the same criteria you use for other terms.

Comment: A belated follow-up (thank-you again for your response!) - when doing a drop1 in R does it make sense to drop quadratic interactions first and then re-run the drop1 before dropping linear interactions?

Comment: I don't think there is a real rule about that.